# Generate a range between two alphanumeric values

Tags: php, range

I have a set of data where each item has a 'range from' and 'range to' string of varying types. For example the first item might have 3001A -> 4000A and the next item might be DE25500 -> DE27419 and so on (with several different patterns but usually consisting of a static section and a range section (it seems that usually any letter is static and numbers can either be static or not).

Is there any ready built function in PHP that can cope with generating the intermediate values in the range? Or if not any tips on how to build one?

Comment: `"with several different...it seems..."` If you can accurately define the rules for this problem, then you can get an answer, otherwise its all just guessing.

Comment: This is true sorry for being overly vague. assume that the two examples given are the main patterns we see in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a function to do this in the end...

```
function generateRange($startString, $endString, $step = 1)
{
    if (strlen($startString) !== strlen($endString)) {
        throw new LogicException('Strings must be equal in length');
    }

    // Get position of first character difference
    $position = mb_strlen(mb_strcut($startString, 0, strspn($startString ^ $endString, "\0")));
    if (!is_numeric($startString[$position]) || !is_numeric($endString[$position])) {
        throw new LogicException('The first character difference is not numeric');
    }

    // Get sequence
    $length = strspn($startString, '1234567890', $position);
    $prefix = substr($startString, 0, $position);
    $suffix = substr($startString, $position + $length);
    $start  = substr($startString, $position, $length);
    $end    = substr($endString, $position, $length);

    if ($start < $end) {
        if ($step <= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be positive');
        }
        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += $step) {
            yield $prefix . str_pad($i, $length, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . $suffix;
        }
    } else {
        if ($step >= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be negative');
        }
        for ($i = $start; $i >= $end; $i += $step) {
            yield $prefix . str_pad($i, $length, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . $suffix;
        }
    }
}
```

Only works when the ranges are equal length at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert but couldnt you use a for loop for that.

You will need to extract the parts of your values that represent the ranges and then start the loop from the lowest to the highest.

```
$min = (int) substr("DE25500", 2)
$max = (int) substr("DE27419", 2)
for ($x = $min; $x <= $max; $x++) {
    // logic in here
}
```

Comment: That would work if all the data was just 2 letters and then the range, but it can eb DE, 2DE, the range and then DE etc so I need some way of detecting what changes and what doesn't rather than depending on a set number of chars

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to first find all the patterns and then write functions that knows how to subdivide the numeric part from the litteral one.
Then to work with ranges in PHP you can use http://php.net/range

Comment: unfortunately the data may change or be amended with different patterns so pattern detection is essential to this task really

Comment: well I guess there's no magic function in PHP that can detect the patterns for you. You should at least know that patterns can be made by a number and then by a letter or by two letters and then by a number

Comment: seltzlab See my answer above. Detects the pattern and then calculates the range.